# Integrating Paypal SDK with native iOS App

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am referring and integrating [PayPal-iOS-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK) with my native iOS app.

I have successfully integrated the app(this is what I feel )

Please refer the code

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        PayPalMobile .initializeWithClientIdsForEnvironments([PayPalEnvironmentProduction: "YOUR_CLIENT_ID_FOR_PRODUCTION",
            PayPalEnvironmentSandbox: "SANDBOX CODE"])
        return true
    }
```

`View Controller`

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  PaypalDemo
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,PayPalPaymentDelegate  {

    var environment:String = PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork {
        willSet(newEnvironment) {
            if (newEnvironment != environment) {
                PayPalMobile.preconnectWithEnvironment(newEnvironment)
            }
        }
    }



    #if HAS_CARDIO
    // You should use the PayPal-iOS-SDK+card-Sample-App target to enable this setting.
    // For your apps, you will need to link to the libCardIO and dependent libraries. Please read the README.md
    // for more details.
    var acceptCreditCards: Bool = true {
    didSet {
    payPalConfig.acceptCreditCards = acceptCreditCards
    }
    }
    #else
    var acceptCreditCards: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            payPalConfig.acceptCreditCards = acceptCreditCards
        }
    }
    #endif


    var resultText = "" // empty
    var payPalConfig = PayPalConfiguration() // default



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        title = "PayPal SDK Demo"
        //successView.hidden = true

        // Set up payPalConfig
        print("this is credit card status \(acceptCreditCards)")
        payPalConfig.acceptCreditCards = true;
        payPalConfig.merchantName = "Awesome Shirts, Inc."
        payPalConfig.merchantPrivacyPolicyURL = NSURL(string: "https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/ua/privacy-full")
        payPalConfig.merchantUserAgreementURL = NSURL(string: "https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/ua/useragreement-full")



        payPalConfig.languageOrLocale = NSLocale.preferredLanguages()[0]

        // Setting the payPalShippingAddressOption property is optional.
        //
        // See PayPalConfiguration.h for details.

        payPalConfig.payPalShippingAddressOption = .PayPal;

        print("PayPal iOS SDK Version: \(PayPalMobile.libraryVersion())")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        PayPalMobile.preconnectWithEnvironment(environment)
    }


    @IBAction func payByPaypal(sender: UIButton) {
        print("integrate paypal here")
        resultText = ""

        // Note: For purposes of illustration, this example shows a payment that includes
        //       both payment details (subtotal, shipping, tax) and multiple items.
        //       You would only specify these if appropriate to your situation.
        //       Otherwise, you can leave payment.items and/or payment.paymentDetails nil,
        //       and simply set payment.amount to your total charge.

        // Optional: include multiple items
        let item1 = PayPalItem(name: "Old jeans with holes", withQuantity: 2, withPrice: NSDecimalNumber(string: "84.99"), withCurrency: "USD", withSku: "Hip-0037")
        let item2 = PayPalItem(name: "Free rainbow patch", withQuantity: 1, withPrice: NSDecimalNumber(string: "0.00"), withCurrency: "USD", withSku: "Hip-00066")
        let item3 = PayPalItem(name: "Long-sleeve plaid shirt (mustache not included)", withQuantity: 1, withPrice: NSDecimalNumber(string: "37.99"), withCurrency: "USD", withSku: "Hip-00291")

        let items = [item1, item2, item3]
        let subtotal = PayPalItem.totalPriceForItems(items)

        // Optional: include payment details
        let shipping = NSDecimalNumber(string: "5.99")
        let tax = NSDecimalNumber(string: "2.50")
        let paymentDetails = PayPalPaymentDetails(subtotal: subtotal, withShipping: shipping, withTax: tax)

        let total = subtotal.decimalNumberByAdding(shipping).decimalNumberByAdding(tax)

        let payment = PayPalPayment(amount: total, currencyCode: "AUD", shortDescription: "My Shop", intent: .Sale)

        payment.items = items
        payment.paymentDetails = paymentDetails

        if (payment.processable) {
            let paymentViewController = PayPalPaymentViewController(payment: payment, configuration: payPalConfig, delegate: self)
            presentViewController(paymentViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else {
            // This particular payment will always be processable. If, for
            // example, the amount was negative or the shortDescription was
            // empty, this payment wouldn't be processable, and you'd want
            // to handle that here.
            print("Payment not processalbe: \(payment)")
        }
    }


    func payPalPaymentDidCancel(paymentViewController: PayPalPaymentViewController) {
        print("PayPal Payment Cancelled")
        resultText = ""
        // successView.hidden = true
        paymentViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    func payPalPaymentViewController(paymentViewController: PayPalPaymentViewController, didCompletePayment completedPayment: PayPalPayment) {
        print("PayPal Payment Success !")
        paymentViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { () -> Void in
            // send completed confirmaion to your server
          //  print("Here is your proof of payment:\n\n\(completedPayment.confirmation)\n\nSend this to your server for confirmation and fulfillment.")

            self.resultText = completedPayment.description
            self.showSuccess(completedPayment.confirmation)
        })
    }

    func showSuccess(inputString: NSObject) {

        print("this is done successfully :) ")
        print("send this to server \(inputString)")
    }



}
```

My concerns regarding the app is

1.Whatever login I am using I am able to login . I have tried `tim@cook.com` as email and `1234` as password, still I was able to login.

2.I have tried using credit card as 4242-4242-4242-4242, cvv 123 12/12 and still payment was successful.

3.These are responses I am getting
`[client: {
    environment = mock;
    "paypal_sdk_version" = "2.14.3";
    platform = iOS;
    "product_name" = "PayPal iOS SDK";
}, response_type: payment, response: {
    "create_time" = "2016-08-01T09:16:40Z";
    id = "PAY-NONETWORKPAYIDEXAMPLE123";
    intent = sale;
    state = approved;
}]`
 for another,
`{
    client =     {
        environment = mock;
        "paypal_sdk_version" = "2.14.3";
        platform = iOS;
        "product_name" = "PayPal iOS SDK";
    };
    response =     {
        "create_time" = "2016-08-01T09:59:31Z";
        id = "API-PAYMENT-ID-1843";
        intent = sale;
        state = approved;
    };
    "response_type" = payment;
}`

4. Is the integration successful, or is there something that I am missing, because in response from paypal I don't find unique order id, not amount that has been charged from the user.

**EDIT 1**
This is info I am getting from

print("this is also info (completedPayment.description)")
from

```
func payPalPaymentViewController(paymentViewController: PayPalPaymentViewController, didCompletePayment completedPayment: PayPalPayment) 
`CurrencyCode: AUD

Amount: 216.46

Short Description: My Shop

Intent: sale

Processable: Already processed

Display: $216.46

Confirmation: {

    client =     {

        environment = mock;

        "paypal_sdk_version" = "2.14.3";

        platform = iOS;

        "product_name" = "PayPal iOS SDK";

    };

    response =     {

        "create_time" = "2016-08-01T11:05:51Z";

        id = "PAY-NONETWORKPAYIDEXAMPLE123";

        intent = sale;

        state = approved;

    };

    "response_type" = payment;

}

Details: Subtotal: 207.97, Shipping: 5.99, Tax: 2.5

Shipping Address: (null)

Invoice Number: (null)

Custom: (null)

Soft Descriptor: (null)

BN code: (null)

Item: '{2|Old jeans with holes|84.99|USD|Hip-0037}'

Item: '{1|Free rainbow patch|0.00|USD|Hip-00066}'

Item: '{1|Long-sleeve plaid shirt (mustache not included)|37.99|USD|Hip-00291}'`
```

Please correct, me where I am lacking.

Comment: Your JSON is invalid. Please post the correct JSON format by validating your JSON [here](http://jsonlint.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go through below code

```
var environment:String = PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork {
        willSet(newEnvironment) {
            if (newEnvironment != environment) {
                PayPalMobile.preconnectWithEnvironment(newEnvironment)
            }
        }
    }
```

Which is no network environment it will give you all the time success.

You need to change environment as per your requirement. For e.g. If you have sandbox user registered on PayPal then you need to change like this

```
 var environment:String = PayPalEnvironmentSandbox
        {
        willSet(newEnvironment) {
            if (newEnvironment != environment)
            {
                PayPalMobile.preconnectWithEnvironment(newEnvironment)
            }
        }
    }
```

And then if you try with any other user rather than registered sandbox user it will give you error. This will work for only sandbox user.

There is one more environment called Production which is for live purpose that you need to ask credentials from your client.

```
 PayPalEnvironmentProduction
```

I hope the above information is clear which you was looking for.

- Don't forget to change client IDs in AppDelegate as per your respective environment

> PayPalMobile.initializeWithClientIdsForEnvironments([PayPalEnvironmentProduction:
>   "", PayPalEnvironmentSandbox:
>   "AYP......"])